# Cut based on condition to another sheet + spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need some help building a simple script that should do the following:

[Source spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hUyapk6FSgPJBsFbSNlM4GPPQ0NWZfJyFTw2yqFIc5k/edit#gid=0)

Check if Col C on sheet *source* equals **"Done"**

1. If yes, copy and paste the rows from Col A and Col B that meet the criteria to the first empty row on sheet *history* + a timestamp of the copy paste
2. Plus copy and paste the same values from Col A and B on [spreadsheet Destination](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1niihiUXZii1gNnifn2ZLNf4JnvLs887mJMp53OcIphA/edit#gid=0), first empty row on tab *destination* + a timestamp of the copy paste
3. Finally delete the copied rows from the first sheet *source* so there are no empty rows
4. If not, leave the values be

Overall the goal is to CUT the values that meet the criteria and paste them on a different sheet and on a different spreadsheet at the same time.

Comment: You need to provide read access to the spreadsheets you reference.

Comment: _to the first empty row on sheet 'history' + a timestamp of the copy paste_ — the sheet will have a name `history` or something like `history 2022-05-22 17:36:55`? In the latter case there would be quite many sheets. Every run of the script will create a new sheet.

Comment: I just added the script inside your 'Source' spreadsheet. Try it (`main()` function).

Comment: While links to external resources might be helpful all the relevant details should be included directly in the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function main() {

  // get 'Done' rows from sheet 'source' and remove these rows
  var data = get_done();

  // put the rows on the sheet 'history' (same spreadsheet)
  copy_to_history(data);

  // pyt the rows on the sheet 'destination' (another spreadsheet)
  copy_to_destination(data);
}

function get_done() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('source');
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();

  var keep = data.filter(x => x[2] != 'Done');
  sh.clearContents().getRange(1,1,keep.length,keep[0].length).setValues(keep);

  var timestamp = new Date();
  var done = data.filter(x => x[2] == 'Done').map(x => [timestamp, x[0], x[1]]);
  return done;
}

function copy_to_history(data) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('history');
  data.forEach(row => sh.appendRow(row));
}

function copy_to_destination(data) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1niihiUXZii1gNnifn2ZLNf4JnvLs887mJMp53OcIphA');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('destination');
  data.forEach(row => sh.appendRow(row));
}
```

The main shortcoming of the script: it doesn't keep formulas and formatting.